# How to deploy django site on Windows server with Nginx?

Tags: django, windows, nginx

Maybe anybody know easy and work solution for deploying django site on Windows machine with Nginx reverse proxy server? I can't find WSGI module, that have support in Windows.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do this. See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071494/how-to-run-django-with-nginx-on-a-windows-machine

Comment: Now, I use django dev server with nginx.

Comment: @AntonBarycheuski How do you use dev server with nginx?

Comment: @buffer I run django application on 80 port (blocked by provider), than configure nginx (logs, errors, serve static files) as proxy 80 -> 8080. So, site is only accessible via 8080 port from outside.