# How to deploy Python Flask Application on Windows Server Using Nginx and uWSGI or Gunicorn?

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn, uwsgi

I want to deploy my flask application on Windows Machine using Nginx and uWSGI or Gunicorn. I didn't find the straight forward document, Can someone please share the complete procedure.

Answer (score 5):

That's because [gunicorn doesn't work on windows at all](https://gunicorn.org/) and uwsgi is not [supported on windows and requires cygwin which is barely a production-ready solution](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/SupportedPlatforms.html). If you *really* want windows as a platform, I'd advice to look at [Apache + mod_wsgi or FastCGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071494/how-to-run-django-with-nginx-on-a-windows-machine).

Comment: How about waitress? Do you have any opinion on this?

Comment: @variable i've never used it